# Spring Data Rest nested property sort with JsonUnwrapped

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

So, I have this class, using `@EmbeddedId` and `@JsonUnwrapped` annotations

```
@Entity
class Order {
    @EmbeddedId @JsonUnwrapped
    private OrderPK pk;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    //...getters, setters
}
```

And this is the primary key class

```
@Embeddable
class OrderPK implements Serializable {
    private String orderNumber;
    private String company;
    //...getters, setters
}
```

I wanted to make Spring Data REST sorting treat the fields in the PK class as top-level instead of nested. Basically, I want to use this one: `.../orders?sort=orderNumber,desc`, instead of `.../orders?sort=pk.orderNumber,desc`. I couldn't find any way to do this in the documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can no longer achieve your goal, if you are using the `@EmbeddedId` option to implement your composite key. The reason is that the attributes under the hood of EmbeddedId class cannot be taken out as flat parameters.

Note that `@JsonUnwrapped` is **not** intended to perform that task.

You can use the following option instead of @EmbeddedId to achieve your goal.

- Use `@IdClass`. Follow this [example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/composite-primary-key.html).